# VS2017 Entity Framework Failed to retrieve data for this request

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection

When trying to add a new EF Connection to a SQL Server I get this exception:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumResult.set_CommandElapsedTime(System.TimeSpan)

Facts:

- "Test Connection" works fine
- It does not matter which database I try to connect (tried different sources, on premises and SQL Azure)
- It used to work before
- Reinstalling EF SDK did not help
- The error message appears immediately after clicking "OK" (no delay)

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Re-install VS2017 solving the problem!

Comment: Tried reparing before reinstalling, but it didn't help. Only full uninstallation and reinstallation worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Installing Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) 
Fixed it for me

[Download it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I have given the essential part in my answer. The link is only where the software can be downloaded from. If the link becomes invalid the reader can Google what I have answered and find the new link.

Comment: Didn't help me. Only reinstallation of VS2017 fixed the issue.